# Take date from Form Data but Time from Actual Time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

In one Form the user also has to specify a date for example the `21.04.2014`:

So when a post request is sent to the rails-application, to save a post there is also provided a `created_at` data in the request:

```
post[text]:"First Message"  
post[created_at]:21.04.2014
```

So at the end a message is saved. Now when i try to get the `created_at` for the message:

```
Message.find(1).created_at
>> 2014-04-21 00:00:00
```

But i would like that the time corresponds to the actual time when the message was created, so the ouput must look something like this:

```
>> 2014-04-21 19:52:07
```

How do i have to save the message so that it meets my concept? Thanks

Actual i save a message like this:

```
@user.message.new(message_params) 

def diagnosis_params
  params[:message].permit(:created_at, :text)
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
dt = Date.parse('21.04.2014')
# => Mon, 21 Apr 2014

tm = Time.zone.now
# => Tue, 22 Apr 2014 00:34:07 MSK +04:00

created_at = DateTime.new(dt.year, dt.month, dt.day, tm.hour, tm.min, tm.sec)
# => Mon, 21 Apr 2014 00:34:07 +0000
```

Not very elegant but you can create some utility method...